# Mulitiple partners: macho man vs. easy woman?

Tags: social-psychology, emotion, evolution

I sometimes hear from my friends that a man who has many female sexual partners is regarded as macho. But on the other hand, a woman with a lot of one-night stands is thought to be easy and desperate (without even mentioning harsher words).

So what's the reason for this? What are the psychological roots? I would say two most important factors are *biological* and *social* but how do they affect our opinions on this matter?

Comment: give me a few min and i'll put together an answer for you

Comment: In terms of reproductive advantage, female mammals can only get pregnant once every 9 months, but males can get several females pregnant in 9 months.  There are probably many more factors, but this seems like it would play a role in sexual selection.

Comment: In terms of humans (not mammals in general), yes, assuming the pregnancy goes "full-term." I'm reasonably sure that was the intended point, and it is relevant in evolutionary theory (which is not the only relevant theory by a long shot). Do try to phrase your comments constructively @caseyr547.

Comment: Before you take people's answers, make sure to read the article on [examples of polyandry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyandry#Known_cases) (settings where it is not socially atypical for one woman to have many husbands) so that the social and not-cross-cultural nature of your observation is clear.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev lol thats what my answer was!

Comment: @caseyr547 you are assuming a lot about what Nick and Keegan meant, just because a social answer can be given (as my comment and your answer demonstrate), doesn't mean that biological considerations are completely irrelevant or uninteresting. Of course, for a clear-headed discussion of the biology without all the social-norms baggage, it is better to go to the biology stackexchange and ask about variability in non-human mating strategies; fun example would be to contrast the classic Chimp to Bonobo to Gorrilla to Orangutans.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev but women are still capable of having sex while they are pregnant so it has no bearing on their desire or ability to have multiple partners. it is my understanding that there are biological factors which cause some men to crave multiple partners that might be relevant but sexuality certainly doesn't end when someone becomes pregnant.

Comment: It has plenty of bearing on both...but you're right in the second half of your last sentence: sexuality doesn't end at pregnancy. It might even increase in some ways!

Comment: Casey, it's an evolutionary argument.  Evolutionary motivation shouldn't be confused with human motivation.  Nobody is saying sexuality ends when someone becomes pregnant.

Comment: @KeeganKeplinger I added a paragraph to my answer explaining why biology gives women more incentives to have multiple partners.

Comment: The evolutionary argument for male promiscuity is that promiscuous males can have more offspring than promiscuous females so a brute force evolutionary simulation would favor male promiscuity.  Of course evolution is more complicated than that, but I simplify for brevity.

Comment: @KeeganKeplinger No thats not how ga works. Only the strongest survive not the most promiscuous. If it were as you suggest spreading sperm was the goal men would be evolving into a species of larger testies but we are not. Chimps have relatively huge testes, Gorillas have tiny testes. Humans are in between.

Comment: Thats really completely incorrect. This is really a whole 'nother discussion, but any line that was "stronger" but didn't reproduce isn't around today.  Many organisms finds ways besides strength to reproduce.  Your simplistic argument of larger testes really underlies a misunderstanding of basic evolutionary principles.

Comment: If you'd like to know more, look up "reproduction of the fittest" as "survival of the fittest" is really a misnomer.  We should probably stop this side point.  If you like, you can ask questions at the biology Stack exchange for further clarification.

Comment: @KeeganKeplinger no the basic principles of evolution are population, reproduction, improvement and culling. Your idea of mass reproduction leads to improvement is incorrect. As social creatures and structures are selected as fit by evolution. You've forgotten the paradox of evolved sterility.

Answer (score 2):

There are two very broad domains of theory that commonly address the [*double standard*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_standard) regarding [*promiscuity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuity). Haven't got the time to lay it all out at the moment (would be happy to edit later to elaborate if you like; just comment on what aspects you'd like expanded!), but as you suspected, both biological and social factors pertain in ways that are essential to consider. In some senses the theories that focus on each oppose each other, as is a common consequence of any myopic discussion of an issue this complex and [*multidetermined*](http://psychologydictionary.org/multidetermined-behavior/). One answer focuses on one aspect, another answer focuses on another aspect, conflicting explanations and predictions arise, and hopefully the debate incorporates this...but unfortunately often, the original theorists who focus on one (their) side of the issue become invested and entrenched in their perspective, and dismissive of others (another example with which I'm personally familiar arose as the [*person-situation debate*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person%E2%80%93situation_debate)). Keep this in mind if you choose to read further into the literature on these theories. The best answer is often the one that is informed by both, or more accurately, **all** sides.

[evolution](/questions/tagged/evolution)[*ary psychology*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_psychology) is the side that argues for explanations in terms of biological factors. Evolutionary theories pertaining to [*polygny*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygyny) and [*monogamy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogamy#The_evolutionary_and_historical_development_of_monogamy_in_humanity%3a_nature_vs._nurture) are not hard to find; even from a male perspective, there are competing motives to address here. Meanwhile, [social-psychology](/questions/tagged/social-psychology) has a lot to say about the influence of culture on [*social norms*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28social%29) regarding promiscuity, particularly in [*women's studies*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women%27s_studies). Again, [a quick Google search on "women's studies sexual double standard"](https://www.google.com/search?q=women%27s+studies+sexual+double+standard&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp) will give you more than you have time to read about that perspective. Bear in mind, these two are not the only ways to address the issue; they're just the most popular and most inclined to address this issue as a focal topic.

Enjoy, stay open-minded, and "trust no one [completely]!" :)

Answer (score 0):

[Anthropology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropology) is the study of cultures what learned behaviour we receive from our environment and the physical biology of cultures and [subcultures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subculture). (The show [Bones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone) on television is a [forensic anthropology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forensic_anthropology) based drama that gives many interesting facts mostly centered on the biology side.) Culture includes things like music, art, religion, social structure. [Norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28social%29) are the behaviours which are acceptable for a person fulfilling a role in a culture. [Gender roles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_role) are the set of norms acceptable for a gender. Now within America or any other nation there is a mainstream culture which is shared by the majority and subcultures which exist inside mainstream or outside of mainstream. Some subcultures are even [counterculture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterculture). Holding a completely different set of norms than the mainstream culture.

Our culture as Americans in a male centric because of our root in Western European countries. Likewise it's also the reason the [mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28music%29) of our music is scaled and its the reason we still find female breasts sexualy attractive. Until [World War I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_I), men worked at a job while the women were required to work in a less appreciated role mainly child care, food and house management. Women were not allowed to study beyond a certain level. They could not even vote until [suffrage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffrage) was [granted in 1929](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women%27s_suffrage_in_the_United_States). If you think that was bad the history of [female sexuality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_female_sexuality) is more harsh. While mainstream American culture did at one time require men to be somewhat chaste but never to the degree which women were required. Throughout all American history female prostitutes have played an hidden and despised but accepted role in society. Only recently have male prostitutes become available for women. In the 1920s [casual sex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaring_Twenties) become available for women but it was very counterculture.

The [sexual revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_revolution) of the 1960s and 1970s changed mainstream America in many ways. It normalized casual sex and many other things. It brought [feminism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feminism) and other changes for female and male sexuality. At that point women who had multiple partners were no longer social outcast or had to keep their sexuality hidden for fear of complete ostracism. Still though there remains a stigma to female sexuality as it is not as liberal in mainstream culture as male sexuality.

In female centered cultures, ([Matriarchal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriarchy) rather than [Patriarchal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patriarchy)) female sexulaity is treated very differently. [The Mosuo Matriarchy](http://www.spiegel.de/international/zeitgeist/the-mosuo-matriarchy-men-live-better-where-women-are-in-charge-a-627363.html) in southern China have a very liberal sexual attitude where sex is very frequent they have no marriage (except that which is used as a threat to children). They sometimes have monogamous relations as long as they love each other then they move on to other partners.

Other functioning societies have non monogamous relationships with a single woman and multiple male husbands called [Polyandry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyandry#Known_cases).

Biology gives women many incentives to have multiple partners. Women are far more evolved than men in terms of ability to have multiple partners and receive pleasure. Males have only the primary sexualy pleasing organs of penis, scrotum and prostate. Women have their breasts, labia, G-spot (vagina) and the highly evolved for pleasure clitoris. Most men are physically incapable of [multiple orgasms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orgasm#Subsequent_and_multiple_orgasms) without sexual stimulants like viagra because of the biologically mandated refractory period. Women have an undetectable refractory period and after they have one male partner they can easily be stimulated by another. You can read this psychology article about the [comparative feelings](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/all-about-sex/201207/so-thats-how-it-feels) of the pleasure organs.